# laravel unit test Invalid JSON was returned from the route

Tags: json, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, authentication

i wrote this unit test for login for laravel

```
class LoginTest extends TestCase
{

/** @test */
    public function auth()
    {
       $this->withoutMiddleware();
    $this->visit('/login')
        ->post('/login', ['example@example.com', "password"=>"1234"])
        ->seeJson([
            "login"=>"true"
        ]);
    $this->get('/dashboard');

}

}
```

but i get this error

```
Invalid JSON was returned from the route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?
```

how i can solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I advise you use [Guzzle Library](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) and make a request to you route then dump full response:

```
        $response = $http->request('POST', 'http://your_laravel_public/login', [
            'form_params'=>[
                'username' => 'example@example.com',
                'password' => '1234'
            ]
        ]);
        $response_array = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);//use this to see the actual response
        dd($response_array);
```

This is useful because you might use Passport or any other authentication service later on in your project. At that point you will need to send header for authorization and you cant do that by native laravel unit test.

Give it a roll.

Comment: i try second one but i got this 
Error: Call to undefined method LoginTest::getBody()

Comment: Then please got for guzzle library as mentioned in my answer